# Can i move a file in an asset folder to an asset sub-folder?

Tags: android, directory, assets, subdirectory

i have a file in the asset folder, and when i press a button in my program i have to move that file in a sub-folder(run-time). Can it be done?

i have to do this:
assets/file.txt -> assets/aaa/file.txt

Answer (score 1):

No your assets are compiled into your apk file. Consider storing a persistent preference marking whatever you are trying to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it. You can't write anything inside the assets folder programmatically. Better option is to use internal storage. You can use Files Folder in the internal storage. See [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:** Once you have an .apk file it is read only, so you can't add, delete or modify in it,

**Alternate:**
though you can use the sqlite DB for the purpose... where you can save file in hierarchy  using blob type and you can modify it through queries...