# How to create Android App which work online as well as offline?

Tags: android, database, web-services

I want to create one app which should work online as well as offline. If internet connectivity is there it should use otherwise use the history.

I am confused about some possibilities, like this:

How to manage the physical resources like a images, video etc..
How to update the local database according to the webservice?
How to get new physical resources from net when local database update?

About this I do some work which explain below.

I get the all database of webserver and dump in to the sqlite and store in system folder.
I get the all resources like a images and font and video store in system folder like a drawable and assest and raw folder.

My main problem is there when any update in webservice then how I can update the local resources.

One big problem is physical resources how I can manage and get this and store in local?

Please give some ideas i am stuck
thanks in advance

Comment: Download some image and video ,when net connetion available ..this image and video display when network is not available that time display this ...  see this link for resource problem Once you have an .apk file it is read only, so you can't add, delete or modify in it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361288/can-i-move-a-file-in-an-asset-folder-to-an-asset-sub-folder

Comment: @AndroidRevolution i know dear this thing but when i store the images and resources?

Comment: you can store image and resource in sdcard .and use sqlite for save that resource link.

Comment: but in sdcard the resources access by user then how to secure this?

Comment: used file encryption when store file in sdcard and decryption when use this file .

Comment: ok then how to update the database according the webservice database ?i use the same database as server database

Comment: check internet connection and create some background service which update your database.don't use whole data base only related data store in sqlite.

Comment: @Android Revolution  But in Future i want to add the admin part so i can use the whole database.so i need to update the whole database webservice can be change?

Comment: no change in webservice.

Comment: Please join with me in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual- this chat room   and database not change then how to update all record from particular table

Answer (score 0):

For the first start app without network you can put resources into assets folder. Then on the server you can store version of each category of data and increase it when data changed. In the app you can download all resources on the SD card and read it from there until version of data changed. If version of some category increased you update it during app starts and if you want to update data during app works you can use [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which ckecks for updates (every period of time). You can work without database just save your xml (json) and images in special hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO - If you are going to have lot of data and varies everytime, then you might need to go with the database that way you have lot of control to store and retrieve the data you need. You can store and retrieve the images in the database itself. Basically, you have to check whether he has access to internet, if not, then take the data from the database and present it to the user. As you are going to use Web services, I would say Database is a good option to think before you start implementing.

Note: You can purge the old data in the database whenever no longer needed. Anyone can accidentally delete your data from your sd card, but with the database, users may not be ...